# Ruby String interpolation in a shell execution

Tags: ruby, shell, string-interpolation

I am trying to make part of a program, that will create a folder with the current date as the foldername, the simplest way seems to be using string interpolation but that doesn't work and I'm not sure how to get the variable to be used

```
require 'date'
puts "Start"
datuh = DateTime.now
puts datuh
pid1 = Kernel.spawn('mkdir -p "#{datuh}"')
Process.wait pid1
puts "Finished"
```

the end goal is to make a folder with the current date, but it makes a folder with the name #{datuh} right now

Thanks

Comment: Single-quoted strings don't process interpolation. Make it a double-quoted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using single quotes for the string. Single-quoted strings don't use interpolation. Here's something that works:

```
require 'date'
puts "Start"
datuh = DateTime.now
puts datuh
pid1 = Kernel.spawn("mkdir -p \"#{datuh}\"")
Process.wait pid1
puts "Finished"
```

More details here: https://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks 

was just a stupid move on  my end, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the quoting problems, you might want to another form of `spawn`:

```
pid = Kernel.spawn 'mkdir', '-p', datuh.to_s
```

However, why call out to the system?

```
Dir.mkdir datuh.to_s
```

Or, to incorporate the "don't throw an error" functionality provided by  `-p`:

```
begin
  Dir.mkdir datuh.to_s
rescue SystemCallError => e
  raise e unless e.errno == Errno::EEXISTS::Errno
end
```

Or,

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p datuh.to_s
```

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p